# My iPhone says it's overheating

Tags: iphone, temperature

MY iPhone says it's overheating, but I have felt the back of it and it feels fairly cool. A week ago, I did however drop it in the toilet. I did leave it in rice in the hot press for a day and a bit. Does anyone know how I can get it to stop telling me that it is overheating when the temperature is clearly not the problem. Also I would like to do this without wiping it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take it to Apple.

Electronics & water do not make the best of bedfellows.
I wouldn't consider a day in rice to really be sufficient to ensure the inside is not still wet, or otherwise contaminated.

I also sincerely hope you threw away the rice & the hot press afterwards.